# Syntax highlighting component for .NET

Tags: .net, intellisense, syntax-highlighting

I'm looking for a .NET component that free and include the following features:

- Real-time syntax highlighting (HTML, VBScript,..)
- Intellisense (I can build my own intellisense library)
- Line number

I found ScintillaNET from

http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=15804

but I wonder if there is a better component? Please help me, thanks!

Comment: What are the drawbacks of ScintillaNET?

Comment: You should clarify the question to state whether you're looking for a desktop solution or a web solution.

Comment: Does ScintillaNET not work on 64 bits or is it just me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use ICSharpCode.TextEditor, which is the editing control used in [SharpDevelop](http://icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx). I don't think it's available as a separate download, but you can get it with SharpDevelop.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider trying out the [Visual Studio Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685612.aspx) or [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) both offer platforms to build very powerful IDE's.

Answer (score 2):

Give a look to the [dotNetFireball project](https://web.archive.org/web/20180120035529/http://dotnetfireball.codeplex.com:80/), it looks very interesting, and it's open source.

[image: Fireball]
<sub>(source: [codeplex.com](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=dotnetfireball&DownloadId=19660))</sub>

[image]

Comment: Just be aware that the Fireball project was disingenuously forked from an existing open-source project, SyntaxBox (http://code.google.com/p/alsing/wiki/SyntaxBox), with all references to the existing author being stripped away and made untracable.